# A simple matrix multiplication throws an error "shapes (2,3) and (2,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)"?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two matrix, which gives me an error "shapes (2,3) and (2,3) not aligned: 3 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)". The code is given below. Please let me know what am I doing wrong?

```
 from numpy import *
    arr=array([[1,32,3],[2,4,6]])
    arr1=array([[1,2,39],[2,41,6]])
    m=matrix(arr)
    m1=matrix(arr1)
    print(m)
    print(m1)
    mat=m1*m;
```

Comment: This is a math error regarding basic linear algebra definitions, not a programming question. You cannot multiply a 2*3 matrix by a 2*3 matrix as the definition of matrix multiplication simply does not apply in that scenario, since the underlying mathematical interpretation of composing linear transformations w.r.t. some basis cannot apply in such a scenario. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: These days there's little reason to use `np.matrix`.  With the original `ndarray`, `np.dot(arr,arr1)` or `arr@arr1` do the same thing - matrix multiplication.  The basic rule (which you should remember from school math) is the last dimension of `arr` should match the 2nd to the last dimension of `arr1`.  `arr*arr1` should work, because all dimensions match. but that is element-wise multiplication.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica-ζ-- I was just trying to do simple matrix multiplication. Thank you so much. But I really feel so stupid now. Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to do element-wise multiplication (i.e., 1*1, 32*2, 3*39, 2*2, 4*41, 6*6) then you'll want to use numpy.multiply.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.matrix([[1,32,3],[2,4,6]])
b = np.matrix([[1,2,39],[2,41,6]])
np.multiply(a,b)
```

which returns this

```
matrix([[  1,  64, 117],
        [  4, 164,  36]])
```

If you actually want to do matrix multiplication (linear algebra) then see the comments from others above.